# PyUnit: How to run all tests from different unittest.TestCase subclass present in a file

Tags: python, python-unittest

```
import unittest

import HTMLTestRunner

class TestClass1(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def case1(self):
        assert 4 == 3

    def case2(self):
        assert 4 == 4

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

class TestClass2(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def case3(self):
        assert 1 == 2

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

def suite():

    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(TestClass1(['case1','case2']))
    suite.addTest(TestClass2('case4'))
    return suite


test_suite = suite()

unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(test_suite)

fp = file('my_report.html', 'wb')

runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
                stream=fp,
                title='My unit test',
                description='This demonstrates the report output by HTMLTestRunner.'
                )

runner.run(test_suite)
```

I am trying to run all the methods in both the classes in a single run.  However, the code above did not do so. In the suite function, I tried to add multiple tests from the classes but that also did not work and was giving an error.

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3137535/197011) at the question "[Is test suite deprecated in PyUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121107/is-test-suite-deprecated-in-pyunit)":

"unittest.TestSuite is not necessary if you want to run all the tests in a single module as unittest.main() will dynamically examine the module it is called from and find all classes that derive from unittest.TestCase."

There's more in that answer about when [unittest.TestSuite](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestSuite) is useful.

That said, I needed to make some changes to get these tests to work.  Firstly, [unittest](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) looks for functions with "test_" at their start.  Also, unittest's [assertEqual and similar methods](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#assert-methods) should be used, instead of just [Python's assert statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement).  Doing that and eliminating some unneeded code led to:

```
import unittest
class TestClass1(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case1(self):
        self.assertEqual(4, 3)
    def test_case2(self):
        self.assertEqual(4, 4)
class TestClass2(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case3(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 2)
unittest.main()
```

This produced appropriate output (3 tests run with 2 failures), which I won't reproduce here in the interest of space.

Comment: >Hi, Thanks for your reply. Yes, we can use unittest.main() to >execute all the tests however i am looking for different option.
In above example, if only one class is there with few tests, tests from TestClass1 will be executed and HTMLTestRunner module will generate execution report in HTML format however if more than one class with few tests needs to be executed using `suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestClass1)` code, then there is a problem since the mentioned code only takes a single class name and that code is required for HTMLTestRunner module to run.

Comment: @user1521643: The question you asked was how to get all the tests to run, and I answered that. If there were other requirements, it would have been good to state that. For instance, why isn't using `unittest.main()` suitable for your purposes?  Also, you state that you were getting an error, it would be good to tell what that was.  I'm not familiar with how HTMLTestRunner works, so maybe that explains some of my lack of understanding here.  Having said that, I think it would serve you well to learn more of the basics of `unittest` - and how to ask a good question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry for not being descriptive in my questions or providing complete information. This was actually my first question on this forum and going forward will definitely try to learn asking questions more effectively. BTW I found some useful piece of code from link "Is test suite deprecated in PyUnit?:" in your comment which pointed me the right direction. Currently i am working on it and let's see if it can solve my issue. Anyways thanks and really appreciate your help.